# Using Mogenerator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, mogenerator

I've have been using catagories up until now but with the start of a new project I had a look around for new toys to play with and found **mogenerator**.

I've managed to generate the _entity and entity files, great. But now what?
Am I supposed to put all my code in entity? Do I have to manually add all the new properties now that I cant use the generate nsmo subclass? How do I use the additional methods in _entity, must I import the _entity or the entity files or both?

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone encountering the same problem.

Things seemed to be going wrong because the Entity classes should inherit from the _Entity class. I didnt pick this up from any of the guides but it seems obvious now! Then the Entity class can be a blank implementation if you like.